# How to put multiple update statements in Python Script

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am using Python script to update few records on MySQL table.
I am trying to put multiple update statements into line and using execute method and  getting syntax error while executing the python script.

Is this something achievable ?

Eg.

```
Query="""UPDATE STATEMENT1;
         UPDATE STATEMENT2;"""
conn.execute(Query)

Error :

(pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
```

Comment: You can't do multiple queries in a single call. Do them in separate calls.

Comment: Never trim error messages, citate them fully.

Comment: Show the `STATEMENT` as you may be able to combine in one `SET` call.

Answer (score 0):

You can update multiple rows using properly the `WHERE` satatement. **Same data diferent rows**.

```
UPDATE students
SET score1 = 5,
    score2 = 8
WHERE id IN (1,2,4,8);
```

Also you form is complete correct. It was similar that these:

```
UPDATE students
SET score1 = 5,
    score2 = 8
WHERE id = 1;

UPDATE students
SET score1 = 5,
    score2 = 8
WHERE id = 2;

UPDATE students
SET score1 = 5,
    score2 = 8
WHERE id = 4;

UPDATE students
SET score1 = 5,
    score2 = 8
WHERE id = 8;
```

If you want to proceed using the second form you have to execute multiple times. You can use different forms.

If there are only 2 queries to update you can done these:

```
query1 = "UPDATE STATEMENT1;"
conn.execute(query1)

query1 = "UPDATE STATEMENT2;"
conn.execute(query2)
```

If you want to do something more elaborated or you do not know exactly the number of queries that you need to do you can do these:

```
queries = ["UPDATE STATEMENT1;","UPDATE STATEMENT2;","UPDATE STATEMENT3;"]

for i, query in enumerate(queries):
    conn.execute(query)
```

Then you only need to `.append()` queries to the queries list.